# An exception of type System.ArgumentException occured

Tags: powerbi, visualization

I'm using some visualization in power bi for forecasting like ARIMA, Tbats, Neural Network, ... every thing is ok in power bi desktop but when publishing in report service shows the message can't display the visualization and when clicking more details shows: An exception of type System.ArgumentException occurred.
Also I have to mention I use SSAS for accessing data and live connection

Answer (score 0):

I got that the report server does not support R visuals and script also python visuals and scrip. but report service supports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/compare-report-server-service